# How can one display contents of a database to a template from a non Django project

Tags: python, django, database

I am working on a Django project to display data from an existing database. The database was created by PHP language.

How should I get the models into the views to pass the context into the template?

Kindly note, that the database already exists hence I haven't created any models in the models.py file. Therefore no migrations have been made.

Comment: Please read the documentation on: [How to integrate Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for your comment. Following up with the shared links